# Custom slider UI Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, delegates

I'm trying to create a custom extension of BasicSliderUI. I'm just trying to make the thumb a circle (note I'm in the Windows L&F). I've created a very simple implementation that just calls g.drawOval, but whenever I drag it, it leaves a "trail" behind. Any ideas why this is?

thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Can we please see an abridged version of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call repaint on the whole thing, you cant just draw the oval on top of it. Swing will by default only repaint what needs to be repainted, which usually isn't the whole control. When are you drawing the circle?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. I'm drawing it in the paint thumb method. I don't see repaint being called in, for example, the MetalSliderUI. Where does that occur?

Comment: Another weird thing. It seems like using g.fillOval works, but g.drawOval does not (the drawOval causes the outline to hang around).

Comment: did you make your own look and feel, make your own sliderui, or override paint() or paintComponent()?

Comment: I just made my own SliderUI that extends BasicSliderUI

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you want to get rid of "trail" when you drag you should write your custom *TrackListener* and control trumb position related to mouse move.

Look at my implementation:

```
public class LightSliderUI extends BasicSliderUI{

private final Color rangeColor = Color.BLUE;
private final BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(2f);

private transient boolean upperDragging;

public LightSliderUI(JSlider b) {
    super(b);
}

public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
    return new LightSliderUI((JSlider)c);
}


@Override
protected void calculateThumbSize() {
    super.calculateThumbSize();
    thumbRect.setSize(thumbRect.width, thumbRect.height);
}

  /** Creates a listener to handle track events in the specified slider.*/
@Override
protected TrackListener createTrackListener(JSlider slider) {
    return new RangeTrackListener();
}


@Override
protected void calculateThumbLocation() {
    // Call superclass method for lower thumb location.
    super.calculateThumbLocation();

    // Adjust upper value to snap to ticks if necessary.
    if (slider.getSnapToTicks()) {
        int upperValue = slider.getValue() + slider.getExtent();
        int snappedValue = upperValue; 
        int majorTickSpacing = slider.getMajorTickSpacing();
        int minorTickSpacing = slider.getMinorTickSpacing();
        int tickSpacing = 0;

        if (minorTickSpacing > 0) {
            tickSpacing = minorTickSpacing;
        } else if (majorTickSpacing > 0) {
            tickSpacing = majorTickSpacing;
        }

        if (tickSpacing != 0) {
            // If it's not on a tick, change the value
            if ((upperValue - slider.getMinimum()) % tickSpacing != 0) {
                float temp = (float)(upperValue - slider.getMinimum()) / (float)tickSpacing;
                int whichTick = Math.round(temp);
                snappedValue = slider.getMinimum() + (whichTick * tickSpacing);
            }

            if (snappedValue != upperValue) { 
                slider.setExtent(snappedValue - slider.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    // Calculate upper thumb location.  The thumb is centered over its 
    // value on the track.
    if (slider.getOrientation() == JSlider.HORIZONTAL) {
        int upperPosition = xPositionForValue(slider.getValue() + slider.getExtent());
        thumbRect.x = upperPosition - (thumbRect.width / 2);
        thumbRect.y = trackRect.y;

    } else {
        int upperPosition = yPositionForValue(slider.getValue() + slider.getExtent());
        thumbRect.x = trackRect.x;
        thumbRect.y = upperPosition - (thumbRect.height / 2);
    }
    slider.repaint();
}   

/** Returns the size of a thumb.
 * Parent method not use size from LaF
 * @return size of trumb */
@Override
protected Dimension getThumbSize() {
    return Dimensions.getSliderThumbSize();
}


private Shape createThumbShape(int width, int height) {
    Ellipse2D shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
    return shape;
}

@Override
public void paintTrack(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    Stroke old = g2d.getStroke();
    g2d.setStroke(stroke);
    g2d.setPaint(Colors.TEXT_STEEL);
    Color oldColor = Colors.TEXT_STEEL;
    Rectangle trackBounds = trackRect;
    if (slider.getOrientation() == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
        g2d.drawLine(trackRect.x, trackRect.y + trackRect.height / 2, 
                trackRect.x + trackRect.width, trackRect.y + trackRect.height / 2);
        int lowerX = thumbRect.width / 2;
        int upperX = thumbRect.x + (thumbRect.width / 2);
        int cy = (trackBounds.height / 2) - 2;
        g2d.translate(trackBounds.x, trackBounds.y + cy);
        g2d.setColor(rangeColor);
        g2d.drawLine(lowerX - trackBounds.x, 2, upperX - trackBounds.x, 2);
        g2d.translate(-trackBounds.x, -(trackBounds.y + cy));
        g2d.setColor(oldColor);
    } 
    g2d.setStroke(old);
}



/** Overrides superclass method to do nothing.  Thumb painting is handled
 * within the <code>paint()</code> method.*/
@Override
public void paintThumb(Graphics g) {
    Rectangle knobBounds = thumbRect;
    int w = knobBounds.width;
    int h = knobBounds.height;      
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    Shape thumbShape = createThumbShape(w - 1, h - 1);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.translate(knobBounds.x, knobBounds.y);
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fill(thumbShape);

    g2d.setColor(Colors.BIOLIN_BLUE_TINT);
    g2d.draw(thumbShape);
    g2d.dispose();
}

/** Listener to handle model change events.  This calculates the thumb 
 * locations and repaints the slider if the value change is not caused by dragging a thumb.*/
public class ChangeHandler implements ChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            calculateThumbLocation();               
            slider.repaint();
    }
}  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setUI(new LightSliderUI(slider));
    frame.add(slider);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

  /** Listener to handle mouse movements in the slider track.*/
public class RangeTrackListener extends TrackListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!slider.isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }
        currentMouseX -= thumbRect.width / 2; // Because we want the mouse location correspond to middle of the "thumb", not left side of it.
        moveUpperThumb();     
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!slider.isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        currentMouseX = e.getX();
        currentMouseY = e.getY();

        if (slider.isRequestFocusEnabled()) {
            slider.requestFocus();
        }           

        boolean upperPressed = false;
        if (slider.getMinimum() == slider.getValue()) {
            if (thumbRect.contains(currentMouseX, currentMouseY)) {
                upperPressed = true;
            } 
        } else {
            if (thumbRect.contains(currentMouseX, currentMouseY)) {
                upperPressed = true;
            }
        }

        if (upperPressed) {
            switch (slider.getOrientation()) {
            case JSlider.VERTICAL:
                offset = currentMouseY - thumbRect.y;
                break;
            case JSlider.HORIZONTAL:
                offset = currentMouseX - thumbRect.x;
                break;
            }
           //upperThumbSelected = true;
            upperDragging = true;
            return;
        }


        upperDragging = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        upperDragging = false;
        slider.setValueIsAdjusting(false);
        super.mouseReleased(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!slider.isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        currentMouseX = e.getX();
        currentMouseY = e.getY();

        if (upperDragging) {
            slider.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
            moveUpperThumb();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldScroll(int direction) {
        return false;
    }

    /** Moves the location of the upper thumb, and sets its corresponding  value in the slider.*/
    public void moveUpperThumb() {
        int thumbMiddle = 0;            
        switch (slider.getOrientation()) {

        case JSlider.HORIZONTAL:
             int halfThumbWidth = thumbRect.width / 2;
            int thumbLeft = currentMouseX - offset;
            int trackLeft = trackRect.x;
            int trackRight = trackRect.x + (trackRect.width - 1);
            int hMax = xPositionForValue(slider.getMaximum() -
                                        slider.getExtent());

            if (drawInverted()) {
                trackLeft = hMax;
            }
            else {
                trackRight = hMax;
            }
            thumbLeft = Math.max(thumbLeft, trackLeft - halfThumbWidth);
            thumbLeft = Math.min(thumbLeft, trackRight - halfThumbWidth);

            setThumbLocation(thumbLeft, thumbRect.y);//setThumbLocation

            thumbMiddle = thumbLeft + halfThumbWidth;
            slider.setValue(valueForXPosition(thumbMiddle));
             break;


        default:
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}